# how to animation child element using angular animations

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I need to animate some specific elements that are children to an animated parent.

here is what my code looks like

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <button class="slider-button left" (click)="onPrevius()"> left </button>
    <ul class="silder-container" [@animFade]="clickCounter">

            <ng-container *ngIf="currentSlide == 0">
                <li class="slide">
                    <div class="background" style="background-color: #000;"></div>
                    <img class="slide-image" style="width: 1921px;height: 680px;" src="assets/3.jpg">
                </li>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container *ngIf="currentSlide == 1">
                <li class="slide" >
                    <div class="background" style="background-color: #000;"></div>
                    <img class="slide-image" style="width: 1921px;height: 680px;" src="assets/2.jpg">
                </li>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container *ngIf="currentSlide == 2">
                <li class="slide">
                    <div class="background" style="background-color: #000;"></div>
                    <img class="slide-image" style="width: 1921px;height: 680px;" src="assets/1.jpg">
                </li>
            </ng-container>
       
    </ul>
    <button class="slider-button right" (click)="onNext()">right</button>
</div>
```

I have two buttons with a single click event whenever the user clicks these two functions will be called.

```
  clickCounter: number = 0;
  currentSlide: number = 0;

  onNext(): void
  {
    this.clickCounter++;
    this.currentSlide++;
  }

  onPrevius(): void
  {
    this.clickCounter--;
    this.currentSlide--;
  }
```

and I have an animation on the third line of my HTML code

```
<ul class="silder-container" [@animFade]="clickCounter">
```

and define the animations like this

```
export const left = [
    group([
      query(':enter', [style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }), animate('.5s ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }))]),
      query(':leave', [style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }), animate('.5s ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }))]),
    ]),
  ];
  
export const right = [
    group([
      query(':enter', [style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)'},), animate('.5s ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }))]),
      query(':leave', [style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)'}), animate('2s ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}))]),
    ]),
  ];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('animFade', [
      transition(':increment', right),
      transition(':decrement', left),
    ]),
  ]
})
```

how should I apply an animation to img tag with slide-image class?

in my head, It should be something like this but apparently it's not

```
export const right = [
    group([
      query(':enter', [style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)'},), animate('.5s ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }))]),
      query(':leave', [style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)'}), animate('2s ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}))]),
      query('.image-slide', [... do some animating stuff])
    ]),
  ];
```